# Distribute values to several rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, common-table-expression

I need help with SQL Server on how to distribute a row value to several rows with the same id. To illustrate,

- Id = ProductInventoryCode
- Qty = QuantityInStock

**ForDistribution**:

```
Id |   Qty  | TotalNoOfBranchesWithId
---+--------+-------------------------
1  |   40   |     2
2  |   33   |     3
3  |   21   |     2
```

A table that will receive the distributed values

```
Id | BranchCode |    Qty | QtyFromForDistributionTable
-------------------------------------------------------
1       101          13            20
1       102           8            20
2       101          10            11
2       102           2            10
2       103           3            12
3       101           1            11
3       102          12            10
```

As much as possible the distribution should be near equal for each id and branches.

I got something like below, but somewhat got confused and lost path.

```
with rs as 
(
    select 
        r.*, cume.cumequantity, 
        coalesce(s.shipped, 0) AS shipped
    from 
        tmpForDistribution r
    cross apply
        (SELECT SUM([QuantityInStock]) AS cumequantity
         FROM tmpForDistribution r2
         WHERE r2.ProductInventoryCode = r.ProductInventoryCode) cume 
    left join
        (SELECT ProductInventoryCode, COUNT(ProductInventoryCode) AS shipped
         FROM tmpDistributed s      
         GROUP BY s.ProductInventoryCode) s ON r.ProductInventoryCode = s.ProductInventoryCode      
)
select 
    rs.ProductInventoryCode, rs.cumequantity, rs.QuantityInStock,
    ***"how to distribute"***
from rs
```

I'm currently using SQL Server 2008

Here's a sample screen output

[image]

The upper result is 145 Branches, below we use to distribute the ForDistributionQty field which is 3130, I am ending up with a fraction (DistVal = 21.586) which is not correct for this problem, it should be a whole number such as 21, however, if its just 21, then 21 x 145 is just 3045 which is shy of 85 units.

Answer (score 3):

Here we distribute the values, and then make a final "adjustment" to the record which has the largest quantity (arbitrary).  But at the end of the day, the math works and the distributed values are square.

Note:  Not sure why in your sample why ID 2 did not get an even distribution

```
Declare @Table table (Id int,BranchCode int,Qty int)
Insert Into @Table values
(1,       101,          13),
(1,       102,           8),
(2,       101,          10),
(2,       102,           2),
(2,       103,           3),
(3,       101,           1),
(3,       102,          12)

Declare @Dist table (ID int,Qty int)
Insert Into @Dist values
(1,40),
(2,33),
(3,49)

;with cte0 as (
        Select A.*
              ,ToDist  = cast(D.Qty as int)
              ,DistVal = cast(D.Qty as int)/C.Cnt 
              ,RN      = Row_Number() over (Partition By A.ID Order By cast(D.Qty as int)/C.Cnt Desc,A.Qty Desc)
         From  @Table A
         Join  (Select ID,Cnt=count(*) from @Table Group By ID) C on A.ID=C.ID
         Join  @Dist D on A.ID=D.ID  )
, cte1 as (
        Select ID,AdjVal=Sum(DistVal)-max(ToDist) From cte0 Group By ID
)
Select A.ID
      ,A.BranchCode
      ,A.Qty
      ,DistVal = DistVal - case when A.RN<=abs(AdjVal) then 1*sign(AdjVal) else 0 end
 From cte0 A
 Join cte1 B on (A.ID=B.Id)
 Order By 1,2
```

Returns

```
ID  BranchCode  Qty DistVal
1   101         13  20
1   102         8   20
2   101         10  11
2   102         2   11
2   103         3   11
3   101         1   24
3   102         12  25
```

Comment: I'm ending up with decimals albeit when summed up ends equal to the distributed qty, but I need whole numbers only, I don't need an evenly distributed qty (as oppose to my original reqs), Is there any way to control and ensure the distributed qty to be equal while removing the decimals.

Comment: @paulpolo Is your qty an int field or something else?  If something else  DistVal = cast(D.Qty as int)/C.Cnt

Comment: there's a lot of the qty missing, because the rounded values gets truncated, eg. the amount with decimal was 21.56, doing DistVal = cast(D.Qty as INT)/C.Cnt becomes 21 only, thus when you multiply it to the total no of distribution there's a lot missing.

Comment: @paulpolo Clearly I'm missing something in your requirements.  Perhaps some sample data which is more representative of your actual data would help.  The method provided will distribute whole numbers not fractions.

Comment: Heres a sample, 3130 qty for distribution, 145 reciever thus 3130 / 145 = 21.586, if we make it int, then it becomes 21, thus i would be missing .586 * 145, Is there anyway, I could just hack, like get a summation of the distributed as a whole number and then get whats missing and then distribute the missing again?

Comment: btw, the receiver is any number from 1 to N based on the records available in the database.

Comment: @paulpolo So in the 3130 example, the remainder of 84.97 should be distributed over 85 of the 145 recievers?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132015/discussion-between-paul-polo-and-john-cappelletti).

Comment: @paulpolo Take a peek at the the adjusted answer.  Added some logic to force Qty as int because I suspect your Qty is not an int, other wise you would not be getting decimals.  Also some logic was added on the DstVal to spread +/-1 to top N records

Comment: I don't understand "your Qty is not an int" does it mean I have some conversion issues that leads me to decimal numbers, say for eg. MONEY, btw I have checked in the table scheme, the ForDistributionQty field is a NUMERIC(38,4), it came from a SELECT INTO query.

Comment: @paulpolo the only way you are getting decimals in the ToDist is if your Qty is NOT an INT field.   An int / int will return an int NOT a decimal like in  Excel

Answer (score 2):

If you can tolerate decimal values, a subquery seems to give a better query plan (tested on SQL 2014, with some sensible keys in place, this avoids a table spool and some additional index scans):

```
Declare @Table table (Id int,BranchCode int,Qty int, primary key(id, branchcode))
Insert Into @Table values
(1,       101,          13),
(1,       102,           8),
(2,       101,          10),
(2,       102,           2),
(2,       103,           3),
(3,       101,           1),
(3,       102,          12)

Declare @Dist table (ID int primary key,Qty int)
Insert Into @Dist values
(1,40),
(2,33),
(3,21)


SELECT
    t.id
   ,t.BranchCode
   ,t.Qty
   ,(d.Qty / CAST((SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt FROM @table t2 where t.id = t2.id) AS decimal(10,2))) as DistributedQty   
FROM @Table t
INNER JOIN @Dist d
ON d.id = t.Id
```

outputs:

```
Id  BranchCode  Qty DistributedQty
1   101         13  20.00000000000
1   102         82  20.00000000000
2   101         10  11.00000000000
2   102         21  11.00000000000
2   103         31  11.00000000000
3   101         11  10.50000000000
3   102         12  10.50000000000
```

If you need DistributedQty to be an `int` and retain remainders then I can't think of a better solution than @John Cappelletti's, noting that uneven quantities may not be as **exactly** even as you might hope (e.g. 32 distributed by three would result in a 12/10/10 distribution instead of an 11/11/10 distribution).

Comment: Personally, I prefer the precision you presented  (alliteration is fun)  +1